# Should I show all options from a "single-choice question" in a read only form?

Tags: forms

My team and I are working on many forms for a B2B app. We have a lot of questions and we wonder how to display our read only forms.

Today, our problem is focused on "single-choice question". Once the user selected an option, according to you, what should we display in **read only version** ?

- Only the user's choice
- The same list of options with the user's choice highlighted

It also works, I guess, for multiple choices question.

I can provide screenshots or more details if needed.

Thank you !

Comment: Hey Florence, I think some additional context would be helpful here: 
* What kinds of questions are being asked? 
* What value are you hoping the read-only version will provide?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Our questions covers 2 global subjects : the professionnal and his company. All the answers we collect will be useful because we use it to fill some documents. For the read only, my first idea would be : "and if they forget something, how would they know ? they will never know unless we show all options in the read only view."

Comment: At the same time I was writting my answer, I am telling myself : "Yes they would, in the documents !" So maybe, the answer is : don't show all the options in read only view :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to show only the response selected by the user, my driver is that it may not be a sustainable/consistent solution for all multiple option fields you have, think on location where you have a lot of options just as example.

- One thing to keep in mind is that the Ux/Ui should be consistent for the components across your application.
- Second, think on what value is bringing to show the not selected options into the screen? who will need that information? to what purpose? If someone is reviewing results it may be more practical to show results aggregations in a dashboard.
- Again thinking on value; if you will allow the user to update his answer that should enable all possible answers again.

Comment: Thank you very much !